# Collection View not showing image

Tags: xcode, uicollectionview

I am trying to load images in Collection View via PHP, as code below;

```
@interface SearchMainPost ()
{

    NSMutableArray *myObject;
    // A dictionary object
    NSDictionary *dict;
    // Define keys
    NSString *imageid;
    NSString *name;
    NSString *path;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // Define keys

    imageid = @"videoImage";
    name = @"timeLineVideoUserName";
    path = @"TheIndex";

    // Create array to hold dictionaries
    myObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebSite/list/list.php"]];


    id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

    // values in foreach loop
    for (NSDictionary *dataDict in jsonObjects) {

        NSString *strImageID = [dataDict objectForKey:@"videoImage"];

        NSString *strName = [dataDict objectForKey:@"timeLineVideoUserName"];

        NSString *strPath = [dataDict objectForKey:@"TheIndex"];

        dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                strImageID, imageid,
                strName, name,
                strPath, path,
                nil];
        [myObject addObject:dict];


        NSLog(@"%@", strImageID);
    }
}
```

Her is how what I did to implement the collection;

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
      return myObject.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    SearchMainPostCell *myCell = [collectionView
                                dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *tmpDict = [myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[tmpDict objectForKey:path]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

    myCell.displayImage.image = img;

   // myCell.displayDetail.text= [tmpDict objectForKey:name];


    return myCell;

}
```

My problem is the image is not shown in the cell, all the Collection View is black.
I can see the information in the console is shown and i can see the image link. Collection View Cell has been set and set the identifier as “ myCell” in the Attribute Inspector.

I am sorry for my explanation and I hope someone will help me how to show the images.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requesting a URL inside tableview should be in asynchronous, for async tasks have to use [GCD (Grand Central Dispatch)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/).handle background tasks with dispatch_async. also your getting and processing JSON data from PHP in viewDidLoad,it will freeze UI for data download.that is not a good way to download data.make use of GCD for download also.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    SearchMainPostCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *dict = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[dict objectForKey:path]];

        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

        UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
        if (image) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                cell.imageView.image = image;
                [cell setNeedsLayout];
            });
        }
    });

    return cell;
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSCache *imageCache;
}
```

In viewDidLoad:

```
imageCache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
```

In collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
if([imageCache objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row]])
{
    cell.image.image = [imageCache objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row]];
}
else
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
        if (image) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [imageCache setObject:image forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row]];
                cell.image.image = image;
                [cell setNeedsLayout];
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working. But as soon as the image loading and when I start to press on any image, the images start to random

Comment: Use NSCache to save images and reuse, otherwise you have to download images every time thats why images are randomly changing.